# How to I read and write a txt file from android 10 and above from internal storage

Tags: android, download, android-internal-storage

I've been trying to create an app that reads a TXT file from downloads internal storage and puts it into an ArrayList and writes an excel sheet to downloads internal storage from in android but android 10 isn't allowing me to read or write a file. I have already used **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** but it keeps getting deprecated. Do you guys have any tips or know anyways out of this.

Answer (score 0):

use `context.getExternalFilesDir()` or `context.getExternalCacheDir()`,these also work in 10. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage