# How to read all the files in a folder with Mediatore API in Android Q (10)?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, android-storage

I simply want to query all of the files from a folder called `memories`. I have tried looking at the following links but couldn't find anything appropriate or 'working'.

- https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-files-in-code-after-the-android-10-released-2bea0e16d35
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#query-collection
- [How to I read and write a txt file from android 10 and above from internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290061/how-to-i-read-and-write-a-txt-file-from-android-10-and-above-from-internal-stora)
- [How to get the path of a specific folder in Android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451973/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-specific-folder-in-android-q)

EDIT: **Abs Path:** `imageUri: content://media/external/images/media/31`
EDIT: **How I save the image:**

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull String name) throws IOException {
        boolean saved;
        OutputStream fos;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/" + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME);
            Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            Log.d(TAG, "imageUri: " + imageUri);
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
        } else {
            String imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + File.separator + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME;

            File file = new File(imagesDir);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }

            File image = new File(imagesDir, name + ".png");
            Log.d(TAG, "File file: " + image);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(image);

        }

        saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap Image AndroidQ: " + saved);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you added  " android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in your manifest?

Comment: What is the problem with `File memories = new File(PATH); List<File> allFiles = memories.list();` ?

Comment: @hamzakhan I have added that

Comment: You did not give full path of your folder.