# How can I list all the files in directory using Medistore (Android 10/Q)?

Tags: android, file, android-studio, mediastore, android-external-storage

I want to query all of the files in a folder called as `memories` through the Mediastore API. I have tried looking at these questions but didn't get an appropriate answer.

- https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-files-in-code-after-the-android-10-released-2bea0e16d35
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#query-collection
- [How to I read and write a txt file from android 10 and above from internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290061/how-to-i-read-and-write-a-txt-file-from-android-10-and-above-from-internal-stora)
- [How to get the path of a specific folder in Android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451973/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-specific-folder-in-android-q)
- [How do I list all file in a directory in android 10 using Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631105/how-do-i-list-all-file-in-a-directory-in-android-10-using-android-studio)

EDIT: **Abs Path:** `imageUri: content://media/external/images/media/31`

EDIT: **How I save the image:**

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull String name) throws IOException {
        boolean saved;
        OutputStream fos;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/" + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME);
            Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            Log.d(TAG, "imageUri: " + imageUri);
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
        } else {
            String imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + File.separator + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME;

            File file = new File(imagesDir);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }

            File image = new File(imagesDir, name + ".png");
            Log.d(TAG, "File file: " + image);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(image);

        }

        saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap Image AndroidQ: " + saved);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I looked up many questions with the tag `Mediastore` and formed this solution but I am not able to write SQLite Placeholder syntax so can anyone help me with that. @blackapps

```
String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + "/DCIM/" + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME;
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"%memories%"};
            try (Cursor cursor = requireContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null
            )) {
                assert cursor != null;
                int nameColumn =
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                Log.d(TAG, "name column: " + nameColumn);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
                    byte[] bytes = name.getBytes();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                    Log.d(TAG, "file name: " + name);

                    imageList.add(bitmap);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You cannot query the MediaStore for a specific folder. The only thing you can do is query a MediaStore collection for files. Use the same collection as during save  inspect RELATIVE_PATH if it is the wanted folder.

Comment: you can do like this:

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
fun getFiles(var directory_name){
var selection: String
    selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH+ " =? "
    var selectionArgs = arrayOf(directory_name)
    val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY),
        null,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        null
    )
```

}

you need to iterate cursor with do while loop or any other

function call:
getFiles(Lyrics/)    //folder name from internal meomery if you want to use sd card then use  MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL). I have tested this and its working fine for me

Comment: And how do you get a directory_name from a Uri?

Comment: Where do you find `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH`? In the docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.FileColumns) it doesn't seem to exist. Maybe you mean `MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH`?

Comment: var? Isn't that Pascal?